# How CNN reduce parameter and reuse weight?

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution

In the post [A Comprehensive Guide to Convolutional Neural Networks — the ELI5 way](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53), it says

> A ConvNet is able to successfully capture the Spatial and Temporal
> dependencies in an image through the application of relevant filters.
> The architecture performs a better fitting to the image dataset due to
> the reduction in the number of parameters involved and reusability of
> weights.

I don't see how it reduce parameter and reuse weight. Could anyone give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the filter (or kernel) in image below having 9 pixels and the image having 49 pixels.

In a fully connected layer, we'll have 9*49 = 441 weights.

While in a CNN this same filter keeps on moving (convolving) over the entire image. All pixel values in image will be multiplied with those same 9 values of filter (hence we say weights are reused). So, we need just 9 weights per filter instead of 441 in FC layer.

The job of a filter is to identify features (such as texture, lines etc), which could be anywhere in an image. So, we want to reuse this same filter over the entire image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of reducing weight. Could you explain reducing parameters as well?

Comment: We are reducing parameters (not weights). Weights are parameter's value. We reuse the same weight (value) for finding features (such as texture, lines etc)

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the parameters for the Convolution layer using the formula: ((width_of_Kernel * height_of_Kernel * input_channel)+1) * output_channel

Here we can see **Kernel size**, **Input Channel** and, **Output Channel** are affecting number of parameters. By altering them, we can reduce the parameters and it will result in reducing size.